# Create a Google spreadsheet on the fly in javascript from a csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

Is it possible to create a Google spreadsheet from a csv file, on the fly, in javascript.

Use case: I have an application which lets users upload csv files. I want to show them a preview of the uploaded csv file in the browser. I can only think of doing that by creating a Google spreadsheet( on the fly, temporary, read only) in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the uploaded `csv` file, get it content as a string and add it to an array. you can set that array on your spreadsheet.

```
function importFromCSVtoSpreadsheet() {

  //find your uploded file by id or name
             //DriveApp.getFileByName('uploaded file name');
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('uploaded file id');

  // get csv data as an array
  var csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");

  //set gathered data on your sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('csv');
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) 
  {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;


  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }


    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }


    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
}
```

You can [read further](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial)